# Laravel Mix 4.0 can't combine global mix css with local file css

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, sass, laravel-mix

I am facing problem when using Laravel Vue. I put my `app.scss` file and then compile it to public folder using Laravel Mix 4.0. I didn't know what makes it error, but it looks so weird to me. This is my `webpack.mix.js`

```
mix.webpackConfig({
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename:'js/[id].[chunkhash].js',
    publicPath: '/',
 },
 resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue'],
    alias: {
        '@': __dirname + "/resources"
    }
 }
});

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
.options({
    processCssUrls: false
})
```

I don't have any problem when compile `app.scss` file, but when I add `@import` to import another scss file into my `.vue` file

```
<style lang="sass">
    @import '@/sass/public.scss'
</style>
```

then `npm run dev` I got error like this when running the program.

[image: error]

But if I remove one of the them like remove the `@import` or `.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css', { implementation: require('node-sass') })` then `npm run dev` again and run the program. It works well. Have anyone ever got the problem like this? I have tried to change the webpack so many times, but I'm not sure that the problem is on the webpack.

The main point is I don't want to import my scss file into `main.js` file because it will replace my `app.scss` style. I want to distinguish the style between admin and user page

Comment: Can you try `mix.options({extractVueStyles: true, processCssUrls: true })`?

Comment: got the same result @senty

Comment: I believe it's happening because code chunking and it's trying to initialize scss before it's loaded. One workaround I came across was creating an empty `init.scss` file and `require('../../sass/init.scss');` in your app.js at the very top

Comment: if I put that in my `main.js` file.. it works, but it replaces all global css @senty

Comment: No idea why you would have to do this but some cursory googling shows that folks who have gotten this working are putting a tilde in the import statement. try changing `@import '@/sass/public.scss'` to `@import '~@/sass/public.scss'`

Comment: I want to distinguish the style between admin page and user page.. but I have a global css called `app.scss` @AlecJoy

Comment: @Saengdaet sorry, I meant no idea why adding the tilde to the import URL would be necassary, not no idea why you are trying to do this. My mistake, I should have been more clear.

Comment: I have tried to put tilde, but the result was same @AlecJoy

Comment: @senty that's work. thankyou but I still don't understand why I need to import blank scss file. can you explain to me?

Comment: @Saengdaet Glad it worked. I added an explanation as an answer and reference where I found about the workaround

Answer (score 1):

> it doesn't work because a vendors file containing style-loader and css-loader was not being created when using async imports.

This **workaround** worked for me:

Creating an empty `init.scss` file and `require('../../sass/init.scss');` in your app.js at the very top seems to solve the problem.

> This workaround suggests to import a blank scss file into my app.js to force style-loader and css loader to be included in the bundle.

---

I found about that in [laravel-mix github issue](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/2064#issuecomment-511364566) when I had the same problem before.

Comment: thankyou @senty.. I think for now the solution can be used.. please don't be hesitate add or modify the answer if you have the ideal solution to use. I would appreciate it

Comment: @Saengdaet likewise - if you spot any better solution, please add an answer (and give me a shoutout) :) Happy coding